# Nasa Rss feed Sax parsing error

Tags: java, xml, rss, sax, saxparser

I am trying to write a java program for reading NASA Rss feed.The code works but when the code encounters   's   symbol ,it doesnot read the entire line.
For example-"A new NASA study finds the last remaining section of Antarctica&#039 ;s Larsen B Ice Shelf, which partially collapsed in 2002, is quickly weakening and likely to disintegrate completely before the end of the decade".
In this above line the code does not read the entire line after Antartica.
What is the problem with the code ???How can I fix it???
Without the &#039 ;s  symbol the code works fine.
The link to the feed:"http://www.nasa.gov/rss/dyn/earth.rss"

```
package xmlparseprac;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class Handler extends DefaultHandler {
boolean mtitle=false;
boolean mdescription=false;
boolean mitem;

@Override
public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
    super.startDocument(); 
    System.out.println("Starting...");
}

@Override
public void endDocument() throws SAXException {
    super.endDocument(); 
    System.out.println("Ending...");
}

@Override
public void startElement(String string, String string1, String string2, Attributes atrbts) throws SAXException {
    super.startElement(string, string1, string2, atrbts); 
    if(string2.equalsIgnoreCase("item")){mitem=true;}
    if(string2.equalsIgnoreCase("title")){mtitle=true;}
    if(string2.equalsIgnoreCase("description")){mdescription=true;}
}

@Override
public void endElement(String string, String string1, String string2) throws SAXException {
    super.endElement(string, string1, string2);
    if(string2.equalsIgnoreCase("item")){mitem=false;}
    if(string2.equalsIgnoreCase("title")){mtitle=false;}
    if(string2.equalsIgnoreCase("description")){mdescription=false;}
}

@Override
public void characters(char[] chars, int i, int i1) throws SAXException {
    super.characters(chars, i, i1);
    if(mtitle==true && mitem==true){
        String s=new String(chars, i, i1);
        System.out.println("Title:"+s);
        mtitle=false;}
    if(mdescription==true && mitem==true){
        String s=new String(chars, i, i1);
        System.out.println("Description:"+s);
        mdescription=false;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You have to be sure that you're using XML encoding and decoding properly.  Single quote is one of the five "magic characters" that breaks XML if you don't handle it properly: ampersand, less than, greater than, and double quote are the others.

Comment: Please can you tell me how to handle it.I am quite new to this parsing thing.

Comment: On an unrelated note, please please please give your variables sensible names. I.e. `string`, `string1`, and `string2` should be changed to something more descriptive.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion.Actually I use netbeans and I don't change the auto generated variables in a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer to my question.

link:"http://www.javaexperience.com/strip-invalid-characters-from-xml/"
link:"https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html"

The commons apache-lang-StringEscapeUitls library contains a method called unescapeHtml4 .It removes the html encoding characters like &#039 etc with 's and other equivalent characters.Just convert the URL inputstream to a string and use the unescapeHtml14 function to the string and extract a inputstream from it and call the parse function with the inputstream as parameter.Thanks @duffymo for informing me about the "magic characters".